# Intercept crashlytics privacy dialog button click

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

I have integrated crashlytics into my Android application and the legal team wants me to save the user preference when the user clicks the Crashlytics privacy log so that a corresponding preference can be set in the application and be shown to the user. Is it possible?

Just to be clear, my app needs to have a 3 way preference Always Send/Always Ask/Never send for collecting the crash reports from users. This preference should remain in sync in the preference user opted in the privacy dialog. In addition, if the user has always selected 'Always Send' option in my preference, the dialog need not be shown even once.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here - if you're using Fabric, [this doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#use-the-privacy-dialog) should help you get started with enabling a privacy dialog that will ask your user if they'd like to upload their crash report. This has the don't send, send, and always send options, so not exactly your specifications but it's an option. You can also build your own dialog box that the user can interact with, and set your own options as per [this example](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#enable-opt-in-reporting).

If you're using Firebase, there's a similar doc for letting users [opt in and out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable_opt-in_reporting) using a flag you can set in your AndroidManifest.

Comment: Would you suggest reading the following preferences to know the action taken the user on seeing the dialog? CrashlyticsCore.getInstance().getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore", 0);